# External dependency in Rust not loading from cargo run command

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I am attempting to replicate code I found in a tutorial. I am using the following dependencies in my Cargo.toml file:

```
[dependencies]
iron = "0.5.1"
mime = "0.2.3"
router = "0.5.1"
urlencoded = "0.5.0"
```

I receive the following error message when I execute `cargo run` from the project's `src` directory:

```
Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
An unknown error occurred
```

It hangs at "Updating registry" for roughly 15 minutes before the error appears. I would guess versioning as the issue, however the tutorial that I am using directly states that they included them as a way to avoid version mismatch with the example code.

I attempted to search for an answer but the error code is too vague to find anything.

The results of `cargo run --verbose` added:

```
Caused by:
  the given version requirement is invalid
```

I am now getting:

```
failed to parse registry's information for: serde_json
```

and

```
failed to parse registry's information for: serde
```

when I compile/run with `cargo` with my listed dependencies and with `"*"` as the version, respectively.

Comment: That sounds like some kind of network error fetching that page. Does that URL load if you stick it in your browser?

Comment: Http is working. Trying that specific url now. I'll only comment about it if it doesn't load.

Comment: Could try `cargo run --verbose`

Comment: `cargo run --verbose` is returning `Caused by:
  the given version requirement is invalid`

Comment: You might have corrupted your local cache of the registry. You could try moving `$HOME/.cargo` to a new name and try again.

Comment: Can I just delete the `github.com-XXX` file in `~/.cargo/registry/index` ?

Comment: Just a small heads up in case you're not aware, but [iron is not maintained anymore](https://github.com/iron/iron), so you may want to find another package.